# Spring in application.yaml dont see classpath of my lib

Tags: java, spring, gradle

i try to use conf files from lib, but applcation.yaml dont see classpath to lib

this is my gradle.build

> [image of apllication.yaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aj4zB.png)

```
plugins { 
  id 'java' 
  id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.6' 
  id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0' 
}

group = 'common' 
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT' 
sourceCompatibility = '8'

configurations { 
  compileOnly { 
    extendsFrom annotationProcessor 
  } 
}

repositories { 
  mavenCentral() 
  flatDir { 
    dirs 'libs' 
  } 
}

dependencies { 
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc' 
  implementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:4.9.0'
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web' 
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa' 
  implementation group: 'ma.glasnost.orika', name: 'orika-core', version: '1.5.4' 
  implementation 'common:0.3.2' 
  implementation group: 'org.springdoc', name: 'springdoc-openapi-ui', version: '1.6.13' 
  implementation group: 'com.oracle.database.jdbc', name: 'ojdbc8', version: '21.7.0.0' 
  implementation 'org.postgresql:postgresql' 
  implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations:23.0.0' 
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cache:2.7.6' 
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-redis:2.7.6' 
  compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok' 
  annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok' 
  testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test' 
}

tasks.named('test') { 
  useJUnitPlatform() 
}
```

Can someome explain me what i do wrong?

Comment: It looks like you are configuring Gradle to load artifacts from the `libs` dir which is not the same thing as putting those things on the classpath.  It is difficult to say for sure without more info, but my suspicioun is that you want those sql files on your runtime classpath and if so, putting them in `src/main/resources/` and eliminating your `flatDir` stuff may be the right thing to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything you have in libs directory needs to go to src/main/resources. Then it will be visible on the classpath.